# Android 2.2 MediaPlayer alternative for HTTPS and live-streaming

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-networking

I've created a service that uses `android.media.MediaPlayer`, it works fine with 3.1+ devices and as expected doesn't fully work with older android versions as [HTTPS and live streaming are not supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). There's no problem with local files.

What I want to do is to use `android.media.MediaPlayer` for 3.1+ devices and I'll have to create an alternative for others (base SDK is 8, Android 2.2).

I found a single somewhat useful [article](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/) which I guess will not work for live-streams (as it records data to file) and I'm not really sure if it's a good approach for HTTPS progressive streaming.

I'd like to use a memory buffer with a limited size; caching of loaded content and ability to seek for location is not as important as ability to start playback at all. Unfortunately there's just no information I was able to find in regards to memory-bufering for `android.media.MediaPlayer` or any native alternative of `android.media.MediaPlayer` itself.

So the question is, are there any alternatives to `android.media.MediaPlayer` supporting low-level datasource (like stream or buffer) or any other workaround for HTTPS and live-streams ? If nothing like this is part of SDK 8+, maybe there's an opensource project to fork.

---

There's a bit similar question [android mediaplayer alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946088/android-mediaplayer-alternative), it asks for the features which I don't need and doesn't request the features I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still looking for a way to do this, but I'm guessing a local proxy server will solve your problem. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701249/getting-access-to-media-player-cache/18627606#18627606) for a bit about that. Of course, as you noted, you should disable any seek/trickplay functionality unless you plan to implement it through the proxy. You should be able to implement the server so that the `MediaPlayer` only sees HTTP content. At that point it shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input. We ended up with "forcing" http for 2.2-3.1 devices by replacing URL's prefixes. The decision was based on a huge dev and support cost of other solutions and the fact that 3.1+ devices is a major part of target audience hardware, also the services we wanted to support accepted http replacements.